# How do I pass data from a Model to a Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I have a Model "PreExpedition.php" and in this model I upload the data to the database.

```
public static function createExpedition($region, $ship, $title, $days) {
        $new = new PreExpedition;
        $new->region_id = $region;
        $new->ship_id = $ship;
        $new->title = $title;
        $new->days= $days;
        $new->save();
    }
```

I want to get the ID from the expedition i just uploaded and pass it to the controller. What would be the best way to do this? And how do i handle the result in the controller.

Thanks!

Comment: `return $new->id;`

Comment: @u_mulder And how would i handle this in the Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model :

```
public static function createExpedition($region, $ship, $title, $days) 
 {
        $new = new PreExpedition;
        $new->region_id = $region;
        $new->ship_id = $ship;
        $new->title = $title;
        $new->days= $days;
        $new->save();
        return $new;
    }
```

in your controller, from where you are calling this model's method , get data returned by model

```
 $region='';
 $ship='';
 $title='';
 $days='';

 $pre_expedition = new PreExpedition(); 
 $newExpedition=$pre_expedition->createExpedition($region, $ship, $title, $days);

 echo $newExpedition->id;
```